# Unable to run Windmill, multiple errors

Tags: windmill

I have been having all kinds of problems getting Windmill setup and installed.  I thought I finally got it setup, but now when I try to just run windmill, I get the following errors.  Any help is appreciated.

> c:\Python33\Scripts>windmill firefox http://www.google.com Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\Python33\Scripts\windmill-script.py", line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('windmill==1.6', 'console_scripts', 'windmill')()   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg\pkg_resources.
>   py", line 345, in load_entry_point
>       return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg\pkg_resources.
>   py", line 2382, in load_entry_point
>       return ep.load()   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg\pkg_resources.
>   py", line 2088, in load
>       entry = **import**(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['**name**'])   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\windmill-1.6-py3.3.egg\windmill__init__.p
>   y", line 17, in 
>       import bin, browser, server, conf, tools, sys ImportError: No module named 'bin'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; Windmill doesn't work with Python 3.x. To fix the problem install Python 2.x